# Injecting Google guava cache builder into bean via Spring

Tags: java, spring, guava

Could some one provide a good snippet to construct and inject Google guava's `CacheBuilder` into a dependent bean via `Spring` xml?

To generalize, I need some examples in `Spring` that illustrates construction of objects using builder pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While it's possible to [call arbitrary methods in Spring XML using the `factory-method` attribute](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method), you'll find that it's close to impossible for Builder-Pattern style chained calls.

Instead, use a [`FactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) or [Java-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) for such complex scenarios. XML will not get you that far, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks - I got it running via FactoryBean!

Comment: @kuriouscoder could you share your snippet, I'm in the same boat, thanks!

Comment: If you prefer using Java configuration there is a full example on this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181768/can-i-set-a-ttl-for-cacheable/31926759#31926759

Comment: @anataliocs you're right. these days, `@Configuration` is definitely the way to go

Answer (score 18):

With the addition of [CacheBuilderSpec](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilderSpec.html) in the next Guava release (release 12), you'll be able to create a `CacheBuilder` bean in xml, using the [CacheBuilder.from(String spec)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#from%28java.lang.String%29) static factory method.

It would look like this:

```
<bean id="legendaryCacheBuilder"
      class="com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder"
      factory-method="from">
    <constructor-arg value="maximumSize=42, expireAfterAccess=10m, expireAfterWrite=1h" />
</bean>
```

You could even externalize the configuration string into a .properties file, using Spring's `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Until then, you should use Sean Patrick Floyd's solution (which also has the advantage of being type-safe).

Answer (score 3):

Also wanted to add that you can use the Cache Spec directly in the Cache Manager if you're not interested in different Cache Builders for different Caches.

You're not required to specify each cache by name when initializing the Cache Manager, each new request for a Cache will build one based on the provided CacheBuilder, or in this case with the provided Cache Spec (which results in a corresponding CacheBuilder).

You're Spring XML ends up being extremely elegant:

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheSpecification" value="maximumSize=300000,expireAfterWrite=10h" />
</bean>
```

Also note: don't forget to tell spring you are using caching by including something like this in your application config xml:

```
<cache:annotation-driven/>
```

Which you'll need to of course define:

```
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache classpath:org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.2.xsd"
```

If you're not doing something simple like this and you do want to have multiple CacheBuilders for different use cases then you will probably want to create your own Factory Class and Method.