# Config XML of Guava cache

Tags: java, spring, caching, guava

I want to change config of `SimpleCacheManager` to `GuavaCacheManager` to use the `maximumSize` and `expireAfterAccess` features.

```
  <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="foo"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Can you help me please?

**EDIT**

when i user this config :

```
   <bean id="cacheManager"
      class="com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder"
      factory-method="from">
    <constructor-arg value="maximumSize=42, expireAfterAccess=10m, expireAfterWrite=1h" />
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <value>foo</value>

        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I get this exception:

```
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/applicationContext-cache.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'caches' of bean class [com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder]: Bean property 'caches' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1493) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
... 102 common frames omitted
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'caches' of bean class [com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder]: Bean property 'caches' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1064) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:922) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:82) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:62) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355571/injecting-google-guava-cache-builder-into-bean-via-spring