# How to Cache HTTP Requests made with Netflix's Feign library in a Java Spring app

Tags: spring, caching, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

In a spring boot application using Netflix's Feign to make HTTP requests to a service, is there an easy way to cache and return these cached values automatically? The cache should be based on the parameters passed to the request (similar to memoizing a function for X minutes).

I'm looking for something like the `@Cache` annotation below:

```
@Component
@FeignClient(value = "facebook", url = "${auth.facebook.url}")
public interface FacebookClient {
    @Cache(600) // Something like this.
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/debug_token?input_token={input_token}&access_token={access_token}")
    Map debugToken(@PathVariable("input_token") String inputToken, @PathVariable("access_token") String appToken);
}
```

Of course I could cache it myself using a decorator around the `FacebookClient`, I was wondering if there was a quicker/less code way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Springs `@Cacheable` does what you need.

Check: [Caching Data with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/)

Comment: Thanks for tip. For other who may read this, I found these helpful:
[1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181768/can-i-set-a-ttl-for-cacheable)
[2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-cache)

Answer (score 3):

Feign does not support caching. I would prefer the JCache ([JSR-107](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107)) and maybe use it via the [spring-boot-starter-cache described in the spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/)

JCache is an abstraction for the proprietary implementation of EhCache, Hazelcast, ... so it is possible to change the implementation with very less impact on the application. At first I would prefer EhCache 3.

Comment: Is there official info about feign not supporting @Cache annotations?

Answer (score 1):

Feign client doesn't support caching.

Another better way would be to create a Service class which calls FeignClient and put up cache on methods of this new Service class.