# Spring @Cacheable default TTL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

I generally use the `@Cacheable` with a cache config in my spring-boot app and set specific TTL (time to live) for each cache.

I recently inherited a spring boot app that uses `@Cacheable` without explicitly stating a cache manager and ttl. I will be changing it to be explicit.

But I am not able to find out what are the defaults when there is nothing explicit.

I did look at the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html) but found nothing there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181768/can-i-set-a-ttl-for-cacheable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Spring* is pretty clear about TTL/TTI (Expiration) and Eviction policies as explained in the core *Spring Framework Reference Guide* [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-specific-config).  In other words, the "defaults" depend entirely on the underlying data store (a.k.a. caching provider) used with the *Spring Boot* app via the *Spring Cache Abstraction*.

While **Arpit's** solution is a nice workaround and a generic, transferable solution across different caching providers (data stores), it also cannot cover more specific expiration/eviction policies, such as the kind of action to perform when an expiration/eviction, say OVERFLOW_TO_DISK, or LOCAL_DESTROY only (such as in a Highly Available (maybe zoned based), distributed scenario), or INVALIDATE, etc.

Usually, depending on the UC, evicting "all" entries is not an acceptable option and is one of the reasons why *Spring* delegates this responsibility to caching provider as this capability varies highly between 1 provider to another.

In summary... definitely review the requirements for your UC and pair the appropriate caching provider with the capabilities that match your UC.  *Spring* [supports a wide variety of caching providers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_supported_cache_providers) from [Redis](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:support:cache-abstraction) to [Apache Geode/Pivotal GemFire](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#apis:spring-cache-abstraction) to *Hazelcast*, etc, each with different/similar capabilities in this regard.

Comment: I used executor task with fixed delay to evict the cache. My requirement was dynamic setting of interval and use ConcurrentMapCacheManager only. Unless you use ehCache like framework, it's lot of work to achieve this.

Answer (score 27):

Spring [@Cacheable](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html) does not have any configurable option to set `TTL` for the cache though you can build it using [@CacheEvict](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html) and [@Scheduled](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html), as follows:

```
@CacheEvict(allEntries = true, cacheNames = { "cache_1", "cache_2" })
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 30000)
public void cacheEvict() {
}
```

You can find detailed solution/explanation here - [Setting TTL for @Cacheable – Spring](https://aggarwalarpit.wordpress.com/2017/01/25/setting-ttl-for-cacheable-spring/).

Comment: I don't really like this method. It's a scheduled task going and evicting the key; instead of leaving it to the redis cache (which is what expire is intended to do anyway)

Comment: Not a good idea. If you cache values from an external service and clear the whole cache every 30 seconds then every 30 seconds you will see a high load on the external service, while you probably wanted to introduce caching to reduce the load.

Comment: Provides a very easy way to get the most out of the Generic Spring-provided cache, without selecting a specific one (the OP didn't mention a specific one); doesn't fall into the trap of forcing a specific impl on the OP.

Comment: I used executor task with fixed delay to evict the cache. My requirement was dynamic setting of interval. Unless you use ehCache like framework, it's lot of work to achieve this.

Answer (score 22):

With spring boot, I was able to achieve success with this:

First, you need to add `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` artifact to your POM file.

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

After this, you need to add the required the following configurations in your application.properties files:

```
#------ Redis Properties -------------
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.redis.host=127.0.0.1
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=600000
```

The property to set is `spring.cache.redis.time-to-live` (value is in milliseconds. 10 mins was set in this case). With this, `@Cacheable` works with the set default TTL.

Comment: The above is valid, but only for spring boot 2.1.X per the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider-redis

Comment: This should be the correct answer if using redis and spring boot

Comment: you can use PT10M for 10 min duration

Comment: also this config wont work if you start defining your own java RedisCacheManager bean and all

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a better way than using @schedule, by extending the cacheManager which defines the ttl: Here is an example :

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

@Value( "${redis.hostname}" )
private String redisHostName;

@Value( "${redis.port}" )
private int redisPort;

@Value("#{${redis.ttl}}")
private int DEFAULT_TTL;


@Bean
public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    redisConnectionFactory.setHostName(redisHostName);
    redisConnectionFactory.setPort(redisPort);
    return redisConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory cf) {
    RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
    cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(DEFAULT_TTL);
    return cacheManager;
}
}
```

pom dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: So if you choose this option (I did it), you need to set cache manager in the cacheable method I mean:  `@Cacheable("cacheName", key = "#keyName", cacheManager = "redisCacheManager")`

Answer (score -2):

The cache will never expire by default. If we need to set expire time we have to use the redis cache with below properties key. If the value is 60000ms, the cache will expire after 1 minute.

```
# Entry expiration. By default, the entries never expire.
spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=60000
```

Comment: How is 10000ms = 1min?