# Java Spring Redis: Set time to live with annotation

Tags: java, spring, redis

I am searching a way to set the TTL with spring annotation.

I tried

```
@CacheEvict(allEntries = true, value = { "mycache" })
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
```

And putting `@EnableScheduling` on my `Application.java` with no success.

I also tried `@RedisHash(timeToLive=2000)` on the class with and without `@TimeToLive(unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)` on method.

Then I tried to put `@EnableRedisRepositories(keyspaceConfiguration = UserKeySpaceConfiguration.class)` on my class

```
public class UserKeySpaceConfiguration extends KeyspaceConfiguration {

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   *
   * @see org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.KeyspaceConfiguration#getKeyspaceSettings(java.lang.Class)
   */
  @Override
  public KeyspaceSettings getKeyspaceSettings(final Class<?> type) {
    final KeyspaceSettings keyspaceSettings = new KeyspaceSettings(type, "user-keyspace");
    keyspaceSettings.setTimeToLive(172800L);
    return keyspaceSettings;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   * @see org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.KeyspaceConfiguration#hasSettingsFor(java.lang.Class)
   */
  @Override
  public boolean hasSettingsFor(final Class<?> type) {
    return true;
  }

}
```

All this method don't work.
When I check Redis if my keys have TTL, I always have `-1`.

Any idea on how to proceed ?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try `spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=600000` ???

Comment: I retry and it works perfectly maybe I had a bad syntax or a very short delay.
But with this solution the TTL is global to all keys or I want to put different TTL on different keys

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well after a week of search I found a solution.

To have different TTL on different keys you have to create your own cache manager.

So in your `Application.java` add your custom cache manager.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableCaching
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(final RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final RedisCacheWriter redisCacheWriter = RedisCacheWriter.lockingRedisCacheWriter(connectionFactory);
    final SerializationPair<Object> valueSerializationPair = RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    final RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig();
    final RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisCacheWriter, cacheConfiguration);
    return redisCacheManager;
  }

  @Bean(name = "pickleCacheManager")
  public RedisCacheManager pickleCacheManager(final RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final RedisCacheWriter redisCacheWriter = RedisCacheWriter.lockingRedisCacheWriter(connectionFactory);
    final SerializationPair<Object> valueSerializationPair = RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig();
    cacheConfiguration = cacheConfiguration.entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(120));
    final RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisCacheWriter, cacheConfiguration);
    return redisCacheManager;
  }

  @Bean(name = "userCacheManager")
  public RedisCacheManager userCacheManager(final RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final RedisCacheWriter redisCacheWriter = RedisCacheWriter.lockingRedisCacheWriter(connectionFactory);
    final SerializationPair<Object> valueSerializationPair = RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig();
    cacheConfiguration = cacheConfiguration.entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(172800));
    final RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisCacheWriter, cacheConfiguration);
    return redisCacheManager;
  }

}
```

To make the difference between your cache, you have the attribut `name` with annotation `@Bean`.

You need to have a `@Primary` `@Bean` or your application will crash. In my case my primary juste return the cache without change.

So in this custom cache I just add a TTL with

```
cacheConfiguration = cacheConfiguration.entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(120));
```

And when you use your cache on a method you just need to specify your cache like so:

```
@Cacheable(value = "value", key = "#key", cacheManager = "yourCacheName")
```

In my case

```
@Cacheable(value = "pickle", key = "#pickleId", cacheManager = "pickleCacheManager")
Pickle findFirstById(String pickleId);
```

Your `cacheManager` in `@Cacheable` is your `name` in `@Bean`.

Comment: But doesn't every key in pickleCacheManager have a TTL of 120? How do you change that for single keys?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update

```
@CacheEvict(allEntries = true, value = { "mycache" })
```

to

```
@CacheEvict(allEntries = true, cacheNames = { "mycache" })
```

It can refer to this answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202700/spring-cacheable-default-ttl).

Comment: What is not say in this answer is that do I need to `@EnableScheduling` on my Application ?
And can I do this :
`@CacheEvict(allEntries = true, cacheNames = { "pickle" })
@Cacheable(value = "pickle", key = "#pickleId")
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
  Pickle findFirstById(String pickleId);`
I want to put TTL when you search object.

Comment: When I tried this solution on my method with `@Cacheable` `@CacheEvict` and `@Scheduled`, my object is not add to the cache