# Setting key specific TTL with @TimeToLive for Redis Spring Caching triggers no invalidation

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, spring-data-redis

I have use case where single entries need to removed from the cache at a specific time. The TTL needs to be set on a key and not on a cache level

Following this [spring redis documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis.repositories.expirations) I tried to implement key specific TTL but it does not work. There is no event happing, I used a listener to check that and there is only an event happing when the cache ttl runs out.

The cached object has a field annotated with `@TimeToLive` from
`org.springframework.data.redis.core.TimeToLive` looking at the documentation this should trigger an expire event after the time has run out

**Cached object**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BrandResponse {

    @TimeToLive
    private Long ttl;

    @NotBlank
    private String id;
}
```

**Used dependencies**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**Enable Key Space Events**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
@EnableAsync
@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = RedisKeyValueAdapter.EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP)
public class KikaRestApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KikaRestApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The default TTL for the cache is 5 minutes `.entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(5))`

**Cache setup**

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisCachingConfiguration {

    private final KikaApiProperties kikaApiProperties;

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private Integer port;

    public RedisCachingConfiguration(KikaApiProperties kikaApiProperties) {
        this.kikaApiProperties = kikaApiProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration() {
        return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
            .disableCachingNullValues()
            .serializeValuesWith(
                SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()));
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        configuration.setHostName(host);
        configuration.setPort(port);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(configuration);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Idmap> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Idmap> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing of does @TimeToLive not work together with spring-redis caching.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51308129/9107502) may help. Looks quite similar.

Answer (score 2):

as per documentation

> TimeToLive marks a single numeric property on aggregate root to be
> used for setting expirations in Redis. The annotated property
> supersedes any other timeout configuration.
>
> RedisHash marks Objects as aggregate roots to be stored in a Redis
> hash.

Default ttl unit is second.
@TimeToLive(unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
you can use other values like MINUTES.

**Use @RedisHash on BrandResponse.**
All the best

Below is my working code

```
@RedisHash
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BrandResponse {

    @TimeToLive(unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS )
    private Long ttl;

    @NotNull
    @Id
    private String id;
}

@Repository
public interface BrandRepository extends JpaRepository<BrandResponse, String> {
}

public interface CacheService {
    void add(BrandResponse response);

    boolean exists(String id);
}

@Service
public class RedisCacheServiceImpl implements CacheService {

    @Autowired
    private BrandRepository brandRepository;

    @Override
    public void add(BrandResponse response){
        this.brandRepository.save(response);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean exists(String id){
        return !this.brandRepository.findById(id).isEmpty();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisCachingConfiguration {


    private String host ="192.168.1.59";

    private Integer port = 6379;

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration() {
        return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
                .disableCachingNullValues()
                .serializeValuesWith(
                        RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()));
    }

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConFactory
                = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        jedisConFactory.setHostName(host);
        jedisConFactory.setPort(port);
        return jedisConFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
}
```

I used two data sources one for Redis another for db

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = RedisKeyValueAdapter.EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP,
basePackages = {"com.c4c.authn.core.repository.redis"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.c4c.authn.core.repository.db"})
public class AuthApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(AuthApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Unit test

```
public class RedisCacheServiceImplTest extends BaseServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private CacheService cacheService;

    @Test
    public void test_add_ok() throws InterruptedException {
        this.cacheService.add(new BrandResponse(5l, "ID1"));
        assertTrue(this.cacheService.exists("ID1"));

        Thread.sleep(6000);

        assertFalse(this.cacheService.exists("ID1"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I was setting milliseconds without changing the unit