# Spring cachable timeout

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a multi-threaded, high-performance and long-running process (I mean hours) in Spring. In order to allow this process to cancel I like to check periodically for the permission to cancel this process using a huge SQL.

```
@Service
public class CancelHolder {
  @PersistenceContext
  private final EntityManager em = null;

  public boolean isCancel() {
    return !em.createQuery("..<huge sql>..").getResultList().isEmpty();
  }
}
```

This `isCancel` is called about 20/sec/thread from about 100 threads make a total of 2000 calls per second.

### Problem

If I use `@Cacheable(value="cancelcache", sync=true)` the method is called once and stored forever.

### Solution

I have to evict the cache every 1 second.

### Question

How to evict the cache every 1 second?

Comment: That depends on the underlying cache provider. Do you simply use the default one?

Comment: @jAC Yes. I do.

Comment: Then this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202700/spring-cacheable-default-ttl