# How to set a TTL for Simple @Cacheable without Guava CacheBuilder

Tags: java, spring

I wanted to use the @Cacheable annotation for Spring Boot 1.5, without any external cache provider. How do I set the TTL for the [simple](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider-simple) provider case?

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181768/can-i-set-a-ttl-for-cacheable) and other resources online, I can use Guava's `CacheBuilder` to set the expiry by providing a `CacheConfiguration`.

However, it seems Guava Cache is [deprecated by Spring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18370). So without Guava, how does one set the TTL for a simple Spring cache?

Answer (score 0):

you can try

> Ehcache

add dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

implement cache

```
@Service
public class NumberService {

    // ...
    @Cacheable(
      value = "squareCache", 
      key = "#number", 
      condition = "#number>10")
    public BigDecimal square(Long number) {
        BigDecimal square = BigDecimal.valueOf(number)
          .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(number));
        log.info("square of {} is {}", number, square);
        return square;
    }
}
```

[more details for ref.](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-ehcache)

Comment: Can I achieve this without using any external dependency?