# How to set an expiration time for the cache?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

```
@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)  {
    log.debug("Load user {}", username);
    UserDetails userDetails = userService.findUserDetailsByName(username).get();
    return userDetails;
}
```

When the user authorizes, the `loadUserByUsername` method calls the `findUserDetailsByName` method from the `userService`. In this method, when authorizing a user, Spring writes the user's data to cache and does not contact the database the next time.

My task is to delete this cache within 10 minutes, so that Spring can re-enter the database, since roles can be changed. I know a solution using `@Scheduled`, but I think the given approach is wrong. Can you suggest an acceptable option for clearing the cache every 10 minutes?

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class Customizer implements CacheManagerCustomizer<ConcurrentMapCacheManager> {
    @Override
    public void customize(ConcurrentMapCacheManager cacheManager) {
        cacheManager.setCacheNames(List.of(Caches.UD_CACHE));
    }

    @CacheEvict(allEntries = true, value = {Caches.UD_CACHE})
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10 * 60000)
    public void reportCacheEvict() {
        log.info("Flush cache " + Caches.UD_CACHE + " at " + new Date());
    }
}
    private final Cache userDetailsCache;
    public UserService(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        this.userDetailsCache = cacheManager.getCache(Caches.USER_DETAILS_CACHE);
    }
    public Optional<UserDetails> findUserDetailsByName(String username) {
        ValueWrapper v= userDetailsCache.get(username);
        if (v== null) {
            Optional<UserDetails> userDetailsOpt =
                userRepository.findOne(QUser.user.userName.eq(username)).map(UserService::createFrom);
            userDetailsOpt.ifPresent(u -> userDetailsCache.put(username, u));
            return userDetailsOpt.map(u -> withUserDetails(u).build());
        } else {
            return Optional.ofNullable((UserDetails) v.get()).map(u -> withUserDetails(u).build());
        }
    }
public final class Caches {
    public static final String UD_CACHE = "udCache";
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I set a TTL for @Cacheable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181768/can-i-set-a-ttl-for-cacheable)

Comment: this is not a working option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65177102/empty-encoded-password-when-using-cacheable-in-userdetailsservice

Answer (score 1):

In you example you use `fixedDelay`, but since you want to clear the cache every 10 mins you should use a `fixedRate`.

```
 public class Customizer implements CacheManagerCustomizer<ConcurrentMapCacheManager>{
  
     @Override
     public void customize(ConcurrentMapCacheManager cacheManager) {
         cacheManager.setCacheNames(List.of(Caches.UD_CACHE));
     }

     @CacheEvict(allEntries = true, value = {Caches.UD_CACHE})
     @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10 * 60000)
     public void evictUDCache() {
        log.info("Flush cache " + Caches.UD_CACHE + " at " + new Date());
     }
 }
```

EDIT

> thanks. but I'm interested in the option without @Scheduled

You can inject the [`TaskScheduler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) and then use it when you need it.

```
TaskScheduler taskScheduler = ....;

Cache udCache = cacheManager.getCache(Caches.UD_CACHE);  
Duration clearCacheInterval = Duration.of(10L, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(udCache::clear, clearCacheInterval);
```

or schedule with a fixed delay

```
taskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(udCache::clear, clearCacheInterval);
```

Comment: This is again using scheduled. Is there no other option? is it possible to use another library?

Comment: You can use java's `ExecutorService` but you it does not support a delay out of the box. You have to implement it. Maybe this helps you.

Comment: Maybe this can be done using @Cacheable, SimpleCacheManager, CaffeineCache

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65177102/empty-encoded-password-when-using-cacheable-in-userdetailsservice