# Empty encoded password when using @Cacheable in UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Faced a problem with caching during authorization, I can't figure it out. So that during authorization every time a request is not made to the database, I want to cache the method. At the first request with an empty cache, everything is fine and until the cache is deleted after a time. But while the cache is there, I get 401, because o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder: Empty encoded password, the password is empty every time. How to be in such a situation?

```
   @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        log.debug("Load user {}", username);
        return userService.findUserDetailsByName(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(username));
    }
 
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = Caches.USER_DETAILS_CACHE)
    public Optional<UserDetails> findUserDetailsByName(String username) {
            Optional<UserDetails> userDetailsOpt =
                    userRepository.findOne(QUser.user.userName.eq(username)).map(UserService::createFrom);
            return userDetailsOpt.map(u -> withUserDetails(u).build());
    }
 
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableCaching
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CacheConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(Ticker ticker, @Value("${app.cache.user.ttl}") Duration userTtl) {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        List<CaffeineCache> caches = new ArrayList<>();
        caches.add(buildCache(Caches.USER_DETAILS_CACHE, ticker, userTtl, 1));
        cacheManager.setCaches(caches);
        return cacheManager;
    }
 
    @Bean
    public Ticker ticker() {
        return Ticker.systemTicker();
    }
 
    private static CaffeineCache buildCache(String name, Ticker ticker, Duration ttl, int size) {
        return new CaffeineCache(name, Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(ttl)
                .ticker(ticker)
                .maximumSize(size)
                .build());
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Assuming you are using the default Spring Security `User` as the `UserDetails` implementation. This implements [`CredentialsContainer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/CredentialsContainer.html) which will have its password cleared after use for security reasons. And as it is caching the object instance instead of raw data it will be cleared in the cache. If you are using JPA you better use the 2nd level caching integration of your JPA provider instead of external caching.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using the default Spring Security [`User`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) as the `UserDetails` implementation. This implements [`CredentialsContainer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/CredentialsContainer.html) which will have its password cleared after use for security reasons.

The caching is done for the object instance instead of raw data and thus it will be cleared in the cache as well.

If you are using JPA you better use the 2nd level caching integration of your JPA provider instead of external caching.

Comment: One should keep in mind that the 2nd level cache is cleared on every native query. Thus it migh not work as expected if the application often uses native queries.

Comment: Apparently that is true. Maybe I execute too little SQL queries through JPA, which would explain why I never noticed this behavior. See https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-the-auto-flush-work-in-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way

```
    private final Cache userDetailsCache;
    public UserService(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        this.userDetailsCache = cacheManager.getCache(Caches.USER_DETAILS_CACHE);
    }
      public Optional<UserDetails> findUserDetailsByName(String username) {
        ValueWrapper value = userDetailsCache.get(username);
        if (value == null) {
            Optional<UserDetails> userDetailsOpt =
                    userRepository.findOne(QUser.user.userName.eq(username)).map(UserService::createFrom);
            userDetailsOpt.ifPresent(u -> userDetailsCache.put(username, u));
            return userDetailsOpt.map(u -> withUserDetails(u).build());
        } else {
            return Optional.ofNullable((UserDetails) value.get()).map(u -> withUserDetails(u).build());
        }
    }
```