# Kotlin + Spring Boot - Add TTL to your map

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, caching

So I have an empty map referenced like:

```
private var labelsForGroupId: Map<GroupId, Label> = emptyMap()
```

to lower the amount of calls through network api. After first call I cache the response to the map.

However, I would love to add TTL to that map, (for example, every hour it should be empty again). I am quite new to Kotlin, so wondering what would be the best approach here with some examples?

Comment: in spring you can use a [Scheduled](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) task that will run at whatever interval you decide.

Comment: Why not use one of the many existing caching facilities instead of reimplementing it from scratch? You can take a look at `@Cacheable` annotation, and choose a cache implementation that allows configuring a TTL:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181768/can-i-set-a-ttl-for-cacheable

Comment: I'm fine with any existing caching solutions, just didn't know how to implement it with my map. Again, kinda of Kotlin newbie

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Map, you could use [Guava Cache](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-cache). It works like a Map (key-value) and have expiration policies.

Expiration by time example:

```
CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
  .expireAfterAccess(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
  .build(loader);
```

If you are not interested in caches at all, then you could try to setup a Coroutine with a ScheduledExecutorService as Dispatcher. I never did this before but is a way out. Take a look at the [Executors documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/src/Executors.kt) - [Coroutine context and dispatchers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html)

> - If the given [ExecutorService] is an instance of
>   [ScheduledExecutorService], then all time-related  * coroutine
>   operations such as [delay], [withTimeout] and time-based [Flow]
>   operators will be scheduled  * on this executor using
>   [schedule][ScheduledExecutorService.schedule] method. If the
>   corresponding  * coroutine is cancelled, [ScheduledFuture.cancel] will
>   be invoked on the corresponding future.