# Spring Boot: Cannot set expiration for @Cacheable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, ttl

I have followed some approaches on [Can I set a TTL for @Cacheable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181768/can-i-set-a-ttl-for-cacheable) and similar pages on the web, but most of them are not working or outdated.

I need to set expiration time for my `@Cacheable` implementation, but unfıortunately there is not a proper solution for that. So, could you please clarify me how can I set TTL for `@Cacheable`?

My implementation is the same as mentioned for Spring Boot on [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot, nor should, set the TTL through `@Cacheable`. How to configure the TTL depends on your cache implementation and you should refer to that documentation. The "cache" used in that tutorial isn't really a cache that should be used in production, it is basically a `Map`, if you want a real cache use something like EhCache, JCache etc. which all provide configuration options for that.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Which one (EhCache, JCache, etc.) would you suggest for a Spring Boot app? Which one is better? On the other hand, is there a simple implementation for that?

Comment: I'm not going to recommend a caching implementation as that depends on your needs. Spring provides abstractions for several implementation and Spring Boot will auto configure those.

Comment: What about **Redis**? Would you suggest the approach on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-redis-cache ?

Comment: No sorry, as which cache to use depends on so much variables and it is an opinionated topic.

Comment: At least you can say that if using Redis for a mid level app may be good idea or not.